# How to set a AWS lambda trigger to Alexa Skills in YAML file

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to deploy my AWS Cloudformation - AWS Serverless Application Model but I can't find how to configure my Alexa Skills Kit ID and my Alexa Smart Home inside my SAM file.

This is the .yaml file that I get from export action in my Lamda console:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: An AWS Serverless Specification template describing your function.
Resources:
  endesaES:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      CodeUri: .
      Code: '../myCode'
      Description: ''
      MemorySize: 256
      Timeout: 90
      Role: 'myRole/lambda_basic_execution'
      Events:
        AlexaSkillEvent:
          Type: AlexaSkill
```

But in there there is no code that shows my Alexa Skill ID, I have everything working and I have configured the ID in the web like shown in the image, and my Alexa Skill Test is working properly.

[image]

Can someone help me with information or a link that can guide me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Happy coding.

Comment: It seems that SAM doesn't support this feature, yet. (https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/158)

Comment: @MaiKaY Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set trigger for lambda is to give permission for something to invoke it. So to set Alexa Skill Kit as trigger you can do this.

```
TriggerName:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
    FunctionName: !Ref YourLambda
    Principal: 'alexa-appkit.amazon.com'
```

You can see more more info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html#cfn-lambda-permission-eventsourcetoken).